# UTC string is added on XML Conversion

Tags: java, android

It seems my java.util.date variable is being formatted in a way I can't control.

In code I have a Date variable to hold the value so it looks like this.

Date X;

Date DD = new Date();
X = DD;

X looks great as milliseconds right up to the point where I serialize it out. The date appears correctly in my XML with a UTC at the end. For example:

2012-12-03 12:12:12:345 UTC

So I'm not sure about the UTC string at the end. When I send this to a db is it going to throw an exception. I don't mind leaving the UTC in there if it's not going to mess with anything but I have not seen this before so was wondering...?

JB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format the `Date` as a `String`, in any format you need.

Comment: Thank You. I was trying to format using the Date constructor thinking there was an overload for formatting. I.E. Date DD = new Date("yyyy-mm-dd");